# calendar start on saturday php

Tags: php, web, calendar

i'm creating a calendar in php, but i can't start it on the saturday, i mean i would like a table that begins on saturday and finishes the following friday. i'm stuck :(

```
echo "<table class='table tableDisplay".$currentMonthNumber." table-bordered '>";
echo "<tr>
    <td>Saturday</td>
    <td>Sunday</td>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td>Friday</td>
</tr><tr>";
for ($i=1; $i <= $nbOfDaysInCurrentMonth ; $i++) {
    $p = date('w', mktime(0,0,0, $calendrier_date_mois, $i, $calendrier_date_annee));

    if($p == 5){
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: this will help `http://php.net/manual/en/ref.calendar.php`

Comment: i tried but i only get the start on mondy or sunday :(

Comment: what are these ? `$calendrier_date_mois and $calendrier_date_annee`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) API. I have created a sample script for you below, where the script first checks if today is saturday, if not then it will use last saturday and then loops through 7 days.

```
<?php
$firstDay = null;
$isSaturday = (new DateTime("NOW"))->format('D') == 'Sat';
if($isSaturday) {
    $firstDay = new DateTime("NOW");
} else {
    $firstDay = new DateTime("last Saturday");
}

$days = 7;
for($i=0;$i<$days;$i++) {
   echo $firstDay->format('Y-m-d').'<br />';
    $firstDay->modify('+1 day');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
// Save for common reference
$today = strtotime('today');

// Get the first and last day of this month
$fdotm = strtotime('first day of this month', $today);
$ldotm = strtotime('last day of this month', $today);

// first cell (top left) of the calendar
$first = date('w', $fdotm) == 6? $fdotm: strtotime('last saturday', $fdotm);
// last cell (bottom right) of the calendar
$last = strtotime('next friday', $ldotm);

// Rendering
echo '<h2>', date('F Y', $today), '</h2>';

echo '<table>
<tr>
<th>SAT</th>
<th>SUN</th>
<th>MON</th>
<th>TUE</th>
<th>WED</th>
<th>THU</th>
<th>FRI</th>
</tr>';

for ($date = $first; $date <= $last; $date = strtotime('tomorrow', $date)){
    if (date('w', $date) == 6) echo "\n<tr>\n";
    $fmt = $date == $today? '<b>%s</b>': '%s';
    echo '<td>', sprintf($fmt, date('j', $date)), "</td>\n";
    if (date('w', $date) == 5) echo "</tr>";
}

echo "\n</table>";
```

Hope this helps.